# Self-bagging cops: Was this a bug, or a hacker?

Tags: payday-2

So I just got out of a Payday game.  Every time someone shot a cop, their corpse dropped a body bag.

[image]
[image]
[image]

*And it was the best game of Payday I've ever played.*

I have to know:  **Was this a bug, or the work of a hacker?**

Comment: Never encountered a bug like this. I'm going for hacker.

Comment: If true, it makes me sad that the most fun I've had in a video game is a result of someone hacking it.

Comment: Man.  I'm feeling so jealous...

Comment: Unfortunately that is the case with many video games. Hacks introduce unexpected things, which often end up being more fun than the actual game itself. Seems like a hacker for me, too.

Comment: Yep that's a hacker. It's pretty clear that no police were spawning when, at the same time, it said there was an assault going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be a hacker. Never experienced this. Can't just be a bug in the game

Comment: You've shown no proof of that whatsoever.  It *could* be, mind, but without proof, it could be just about anything at all.

Comment: @fbueckert Well I am 99% sure it isn't a bug and 99% sure its a hacker. Pay day 2 has a lot of flaws but this certainly isn't a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a bug. Like there is the bug that the cops are not spawning at all.